# Как привязать id к массиву?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня на странице есть динамическое добавление полей input.
У каждого из поля свой id (поля из базы данных).

При добавлении нового поля на странице появляется код:

```
<input type="text" name="pole[]$id_pole">
```

Где `$id_pole` - цифра - id поля под которым оно записано в базе.

Значения всех полей я получаю кодом:

```
foreach ($_POST['pole'] as $k1 => $f1) {
     echo $_POST['pole'][$k1];
}
```

Вопрос: Каким образом получить id поля`($id_pole)` при обработке?

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами почти ответили на свой вопрос, у вас $k1 и будет значением $id_pole.

Но в клиентской части, думаю правильнее будет сделать так:

```
<input type="text" name="pole[$id_pole]">
```

Comment: вот так и делаю, тоже так думал. но не получаю все равно нужное значение....

Comment: вывод значения идет как echo $_POST['pole'][$k1]; а просто echo $_POST['k1']; не обрабатывает

Comment: сделайте тестовый вывод массива $_POST['pole'] целиком, без обработки. посмотрите что выведет. какие там будут индексы?

Comment: индексы? Array получаю. или  я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: Надо посмотреть какие индексы пойдут в переменной $_POST['pole']. например array('1'=>'value_1', '2'=>'value_2'). где 1 и 2 должны быть индексами из $id_pole, а не формироваться автоматически. подозреваю, что у вас они просто создаются программно, а не берутся из $id_pole (так и должно быть из вашего примера, "pole[]$id_pole", где pole[] формирует автоматический индекс, а $id_pole как понимаю вообще отбрасывается). сделайте вывод print_r($_POST['pole'])